How to revert a commit without affecting working tree?
I want a script that can revert a commit in a different branch without relying on using my local tree.
I want to be able to run this script while having a dirty tree and not worrying about it.
According to the git docs, git revert only works on the local tree. So I think this might require somehow creating a git tree that is a revert commit without using git revert?
Is this possible?

Is there any reason you can't do it in another copy of the repo, perhaps even on your Git host? (Many tools offer the ability to revert a commit through a UI on a remote repo.) There may be a way to do this without checking out a branch, but the fact that the tree is dirty may complicate it.

Here are some general solutions, Answer 1 and Answer2, to "creating a commit on another branch without checkout". You still have 2 potential obstacles to overcome though before you can get there: 1.) A dirty tree might matter, depending on what you're editing, and 2.) The revert needs to be obvious so you know which files to stage. But if you can waive those problems away with additional knowledge, or even do the revert manually, it could work.

@TTT Can it by done by making a worktree?

BTW, when you say "revert a remote commit" in the title, and later in the question "revert a commit in a remote repo", I think you probably should just remove the word "remote" in your question completely. Unless you're logging onto the actual host of the repo and manually modifying it, you never actually modify the remote. You always modify a local copy and then push the change. Your question really ought to be asking how to do this locally without affecting the working tree. Saying you have to do it "remotely" adds confusion.

I wonder if via my script, I just do a git commit --allow empty -m "wip" to stash it (allow empty incase there are not any changes so keep the script from halting... then I checkout the branch locally, do the revert, push it up, then checkout my previous branch via checkout - and then do a soft reset HEAD~1  to go back to my local changes.... thoughts on that?

@TTT I agree, and I updated my question.. also see my above comment about a solution I am considering...

@matt I assume yes, or you can clone another repo too. I asked about that in my first comment, and I think if the answer is yes to either of those, then the question becomes somewhat irrelevant. ;)

@JDIsaacks your idea would work perfectly, and that's exactly what the normal thing to do is. (That's what most of us do everyday, but I never need --allow-empty because I just run git status to see if I need to stash or commit anything.) If you're willing to do that though, then this question doesn't have much value to you anymore, outside of being academic.

Yeah, that is what I do too @TTT, but I am trying to write a script that automates it, so running git status and verifying the tree is cleaning isn't an option. I think I will work on that solution, and if I can get it to work, then yes this Q will become academic and I can either close it or leave it for someone who wants an interesting problem.

OK that seems to be working for me just fine, I am going to leave this Q open tho because "No longer needed" doesn't seem to be a valid reason for closing.

@JDIsaacks You should either close it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.

@matt Good call, I went ahead and added my solution as an answer.

I came up with this solution. It does use your local working tree, but stashes any changes and then returns them, so even if your tree is dirty, it still works without issue.
git commit --allow-empty -am "WIP"
git checkout -b tempLocalBranch origin/remoteBranch
git revert --no-edit $sha
git push origin tempLocalBranch:remoteBranch
git checkout -
git branch -D tempLocalBranch
git reset HEAD~1

Basically commit what is on the working tree (allow empty in case there are no changes) then checkout a temporary branch based on the remote branch you want to revert. Apply the revert, then push back to the remote branch. Then switch back to the previous branch you were working on. Delete the temp branch and apply a soft reset to get rid of the WIP commit you made.

Note that this is exactly what I said in the very first comment on your question.
